# Why does dot notation returns object with added properties while spread operator does not?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a new object based on conditions. Why does when I use the dot notation it returns the new object while spread operator does not

This line returns the new object with new property

```
const newValue = values => {
 const condition = "SUCCESS"

 const result = values.filter(r => {
    if(condition === "SUCCESS"){
     r.codes = "Success Test"
     return r
    }
    r.codes = "Fail Test"
    return r     
 })

 return result
}
```

This line returns the old object without the new property

```
const newValue = values => {
 const condition = "SUCCESS"

 const result = values.filter(r => {
    if(condition === "SUCCESS"){
     return { ...r, codes: "Success Test" }
    }
    return { ...r, codes: "Fail Test" }  
 })

 return result
}
```

**Expected result should be :**

```
result = [{ name:"Hey", codes:"Success Test" }]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` only cares if the function you pass to it returns a value that (can be coerced to something that) is `true` or `false`.

In both cases, you return an object. Objects are always true values, so the value in the original array is **kept** in the filtered array.

In your first example, the object you return is the original object which you modify.

In your second example, the object you return is a *new* object, so the original object is unmodified. Since `filter` only cases about `true` or `false`, it always returns the **original** object (which will only have a new property on it if you modify the original).

---

You *always* return a true value, and *never* return a false value, which makes using `filter` pointless.

It looks like you are trying to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array, not [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I really need to read more about javascript

Answer (score 1):

The `.filter` callback is meant to take an array, and create a new array which is the same as the old array, except with items removed based on a condition. Here, you're using `.filter` incorrectly, since you're both mutating the existing array items (with `r.codes =` assignments) *and* you're always returning an object from the `.filter` callback (and objects are always truthy, so every item in the original array will be present in the output array).

Because assigning to `r.codes` mutates the existing array, and because `result` will always be the original array (with the mutated items), assigning to `r.codes` results in a changed array.

When you spread into a new returned object, that object is checked for its truthyness (objects are truthy), and then discarded; the object is not used anywhere else.

If you want to mutate the existing objects, use `forEach` (which is the proper array method to use for side-effects only):

```
const newValue = values => {
  const condition = "SUCCESS"

  values.forEach(value => {
    value.codes = condition === "SUCCESS" ? "Success Test" : 'Fail Test';
  });
  return values;
}
```

If you don't want to mutate the existing objects, use `.map` and spread:

```
const newValue = values => {
  const condition = "SUCCESS"

  return values.map(value => ({
    ...value,
    codes: condition === "SUCCESS" ? "Success Test" : 'Fail Test'
  }));
}
```